# Erro no plugin.php WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou com um problema com um arquivo.

O erro aparece somente quando transfiro a pasta para a hospedagem (Locaweb).

No localhost usando o easyphp não aparece nenhum erro.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

"Array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'Array' was given in /home/storage/e/e1/8e/blessviagenseturismo/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 525"

Comment: Pode colocar o código aqui ? é que não vendo o código não consigo saber o que tem de mal a linha 525 do seu condigo.
E para que serve esse plugin.php, qual é o seu objectivo ?
Espero poder ajudar! Cumps

Comment: do {
  foreach ( (array) current($wp_filter[$tag]) as $the_ )
   if ( !is_null($the_['function']) )
    call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args']));

 } while ( next($wp_filter[$tag]) !== false );

 array_pop($wp_current_filter);
}


da linha 522 a linha 525

O erro apareceu ao somente colocar na hospedagem.

qualquer coisa segue link da imgem
https://imgur.com/SlSti1k

Comment: Por favor, edite seu post e indente seu código usando a opção de inserir código.